# Can we create an unlocked package in the salesforce unlimited edition?

Tags: unlocked-package

Can we create unlocked package in the salesforce unlimited edition?

Comment: Yes. We are on Unlimited Edition, and we do have Unlocked Packages in our org. Where are you stuck? How can we help you get to your objective?

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox for the confirmation. We are planning to create a scratch org and do the packaging in our CI environment(Gitlab)., but the below link says "Managed packages are typically used by Salesforce partners to distribute and sell applications to customers. These packages must be created from a Developer Edition organization." So, I was confused here
Reference Link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_apps.htm&type=5

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion. "Managed Packages" are for ISVs, "Unlocked Packages" are for everyone else. They're like Managed Packages, but allow for things like deleting components from the package, linking to existing metadata in a production org, optionally *not* deleting metadata during upgrades, etc.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox, this proves that unlocked package can be created in the unlimited edition. awesome.

Answer (score 1):

"Unlocked Packages" and "Managed Packages" are two differne types, so you do need to make sure you're looking at the right documentation. Managed Packages are for ISVs to sell/list apps on the AppExchange, and Unlocked Packages are for subscribers to manage their own internal "packages" of metadata. You'll want to read more about [Enabling Dev Hub](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm&type=5) for more information.